# mysql process in loop cannot be stopped

Tags: mysql

One process in mysql is take over 98% of cpu resources and whenever I kill this process it gets back with new PID i guess it's in loop. Is there a ways to stop this process permanently as it's causing my site to extremely slow down? Any suggestions?

Comment: What activity is there on your web server? Are there any code that runs long loops in there that is being called frequently? I would start with these first. Usually long running queries are poorly designed and don't have proper indexes.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is caused by non-optimized or overly heavy queries. If you kill MySQL and someone restarts the script the load will, logically, go up again. Try seeing what queries are executing.

Comment: in process manager I get this command 

/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/ --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/sitename.sitename.com.err --open-files-limit=33628 --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/sitename.sitename.com.pid

Comment: That is just the mysql daemon.

Comment: but its taking right now 114% of cpu resources? is it normal?

Comment: It isn't normal per se, but you need to look at what the MySQL server (mysqld in your comment) is doing that causes these loads? I'm guessing large and non-optimized queries.

Answer (score 2):

If mysql is used as a backed of a website you probably need to take a loot at the [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) to check what query is causing this intensive CPU usage.

Also you probably need some new indexes.